# oracle add a condition inside where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5

I have a doubt how to insert a condition inside a where (on the picture you will see what i want to get).

[image]

It means, if my where receive a parameter , filter the result using that parameter on an specific column, if that parameter is null (it emans i don't send anything) show all records.

Is it possible to do it?

i start something but, i'm not really sure how to continue.

Can somebody help me?

```
select *
from objects o
where case when :COD is not null then (o.cod = :COD)
      --else --list all values
      end
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `or`:

```
where (o.cod = :COD or :COD is null)
```

This is almost exactly how you phrased the question, by the way.